# using primarykeyrelated for post and string for get call in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model in which some fields are a foreign key to another model. Hence while creating the object of that model I have to use primary key but while calling get api I need to show those fields as stringrelated field. How to achieve that??

My model:

```
class Example(models.Model):

    tour = models.ForeignKey(
        Package,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name="example"
    )

    site = models.ForeignKey(
                                Destination,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null= True,
                                related_name= "example",
    )

    

    location = models.CharField(blank=True)
    /...........other fields........../
```

My serializer:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # tour = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    # site = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = OnlineClass
        fields = ['id','tour','site','other fields.....']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(ExampleSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        return data
```

Here while creating the example object, I need to pass tour and site as ids but while calling list method I need to show both fields as string related fields. As I define them as stringrelated field as above (later commented out) , I can create the object but those fields will be set as null. I don't want to make another serializer. How to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [the slug related field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) which can be used to target the id (or whatever field you want) of your targeted relation.

Something like :

```
tour= serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    read_only=True,
    slug_field='id'
)
```

Comment: I tried this but didnt work, in get api i am getting ids instead of string.

Comment: Ah, I might have badly understood you question. What you want is basically an input different than your output ? If so you need to override the get_serializer_class to have 2 distinct serializer. If so, tell me I'll update my answer

Comment: I can do that, but what i need is i need to use the same serializer but not different serializer.